# minecraft multiplayer suddenly freezes (linux) 1.8.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The title says most of it. When I play multiplayer minecraft, every once in a while, my client does not connect to the server, I can move but the server does not respond. After around a minute I get kicked as the server has stopped connecting. When I tried this on Windows however, there was no issue. My computer is connected to the internet perfectly though. I have tried to re-install jdk8, I tried to change the Java version to use (which did not work), I used multimc with forge, vanilla, plain minecraft 1.8.9, Lunar client, but nothing fixes it. Lunar client even introduces a new bug, where while changing servers (under the same server-name; like joining a different game, changing lobbys etc.) it just turns black. I scoured the internet for any way to fix this, but nothing really works.

Thanks for helping.

edit: I should specify that I am talking about playing on a server akin to Hypixel for example. I mean that when I am frozen, players wont move, plugins wont do anything, etc.

Comment: when you say "freezes server side" does this mean you are hosting the server? if so try to increase ram allocated.

Comment: ah! I should be more specific, I worded that wrongly. This is embarrassing haha. I meant that my client is fine but the server is not connected? Like- I can place blocks where a build protection plugin would stop it, any player would be frozen, etc etc

Comment: oh! Your talking about desync, it happens when you lose connection to your server, check your firewall and other internet settings

Comment: thanks! that sounds like something that actually something I can, y'know, fix? In stead of some strange phenomenon I cannot name.

Comment: update: I have not really found anything- I have never had any problem with my firewall before, and, as I said, it works fine on Windows, which means that it also is not my network itself.